# php mysqli - burying transactions in a single query

Tags: php, transactions, mysqli, autocommit

MySQli keeps stating that there is a syntax error in the first select part of my 'combined' query as shown below:

```
$my_massive_query =
    'START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT;
    SELECT d.id AS `Location ID`, ...
    SELECT d.id AS `Location ID`, ...
    SELECT d.id AS `Location ID`, ...
    SELECT d.id AS `Location ID`, ...
    SELECT d.id AS `Location ID`, ...
    COMMIT';
$mysqli->query($my_massive_query);
```

Is this 'not allowed' in php? Does one have to use the mysqli functions like follows:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$mysqli->query("SELECT ...");
$mysqli->query("SELECT ...");
$mysqli->query("SELECT ...");
$mysqli->commit();
```

I have executed the query in mysql (after using var_dump to fetch it as-is), and it is executing perfectly so I don't think there really is a syntax issue and that maybe one is not allowed to 'combine' queries in a single string?

I am worried that `START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT;` has some extra conditions that will not be met by just setting autocommit to false.

Comment: [This](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) could possibly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) can only deal with 1 query at a time. To do multiple queries in one string, use [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: I am marking this as the answer over the other, though both are great, for the simple reason that you confirmed: "mysqli::query can only deal with 1 query at a time."

Answer (score 1):

Using API functions you can do *everything* you can do in console.
However, every command have to be called separately. This is very simple rule to follow

```
$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT");
$mysqli->query("SELECT ...");
$mysqli->query("SELECT ...");
$mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```

Comment: Always quick with the down votes aren't you.. You would actually be more helpfull if you accompanied your opinions with explanations..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a quick addon to this: This appears to be many factors slower (at least for me) than using mysqli::multi_query. Also, using this, one has to remember to grab the results from each query, e.g. $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT ..."); but that is simpler than using mysqli_next_result and mysqli_store_result which is required with the alternative method

Comment: it cannot be slower. only if you measure your multi query without getting results.